# What superclass for a custom UI component?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, custom-controls

I need to create a custom UI component that will satisfy the following:

- it will contain a composition of UIViews, Labels, Button and a TableView.
- it should be possible to instantiate it programatically - or - placing a UIView in nib editor and change the class in the inspector to my custom component class. (and it would the maintain/keep the main frame values from placed UIView)

I already started experimenting with it, I chose the UIView but it doesn't handle the ..cellForRow... cell method. On the other hand, if I use a UIViewController, then my class change in the inspector doesn't work and the app crashes.

Which one should I choose - UIView, UIviewController or NSObject?

Comment: If you inherit NSObject all the features of UIView etc cant be get. I would say extend from the lowest level and then use protocols to use other methods/features/behaviors.

Comment: In this case I would inherit from UITableView as it is the most complex UIItem and therefore most of the interfaces are defined already. UIView would work too because it is the common basis of all of them. But then all (needed) additional methods and properties of UIButton, UILabel and UITableView must be added. So in the end it depends on which interfaces the new view object requires to have and to which extend they need to be overwritten. Then I would go for the one where the most of them don't need to be overwritten in the subclass and can just be used as they are.

Comment: Your object shouldn't have to handle cellForRowAtIndexPath:, or any of the other data source methods -- a table view doesn't. That should be handled by the controller you assign to be the data source and delegate of your object, which would probably be the controller whose view has your custom object as a subview. I do think UIView is the correct superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for UIViewController or UITableViewController, since you said you are having a tableView in it. If you do a UIViewController, you would probably have to include another UITableViewController inside it, using addChildViewController, as explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

I believe the reason why your app is crashing is that you you changed your class superclass from UIView to UIViewController, but in the Interface Builder you still just have a UIView object. You need to change it to a UIViewController in the Interface Builder, and select your class as the File Owner.

Comment: How will I then satisfy the requirement to be able to "place" the component in IB "as any other control? Place it properly in the UI hierachy?

Comment: If you mean to have your custom object showing in the Interface Builder library objects, I don't believe it is possible. To add through Interface Builder, you would have to add a UIView or a view container, and you could handle it to have your desired frame in the init methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend this to be a stand-alone component, with all of the logic contained within the control, then I would base it on a UIViewController, like Apple does with the MFMailComposeViewController.  If you want it to be strictly a view, with no built-in logic of its own, but instead delegates that logic, then use a UIView and delegate the table view methods to the controller that is using it.